# Is VMWare Apple Compatible

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, ipad

I have vmware up and running, everything works grand.  I can share flash drives, external hard drives etc with my VM no problem.  If I try to connect an iPAD to the VM I get an error of:

> The device 'IPad' was unable to connect to its ideal host controller.  An attempt will be made to connect this device to the best avaliable host controller.  This might result in  undefined behaviour for this device.

The ipad works perfectly through host machine, Can you connnect an ipad to vmware?

Further specs:
Host system
Win 10
16 GB RAM

VM specs
Win 10
3.5 GB Ram

Comment: How exactly are you connecting an iPad (which is a physical device) to a virtual machine?   USB?   What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Richie086 - I am connecting it via USB to the host machine, then while in vmware going to VM - Removable Devices - Selecting Ipad - Clicking Connect.  Then the error above is displayed.

Comment: Yes, but why are you doing this?  Are you trying to sync photos?  Do you have iTunes installed in the VM?

Comment: @Richie086 - yes I have itunes installed on the VM.  I am doing this to avoid having to install itunes on the host machine.  But this is turning out to be quite an ordeal for something I thought would be simple.